# How did Marty Byrde get the casino boat over the dam

Tags: ozark

Marty buys the paddle boat he will use for the casino in Cape Girardeau and tells Ruth to move it up river and dock it in Bagnell.

At the start of Season 3 we see in the 'ad' for the casino boat, that it is in Osage Beach. There is a big dam between Bagnell and Osage Beach. How did he get the boat over the dam? Is there a lock system?

Comment: I’ve not seen the show, and it’s not clear to me if you mean there is a dam IRL (are they real places?) or if you clearly see it in-universe, but my first guess would be a lock system.

Comment: The places and dam are all IRL, they even use the dam in some b-roll. I guess my question is can I move a big boat from Bagnell to Osage Beach IRL?

Comment: just been googling. It seems there used to be a lock but it was decommissioned with the building of the dam in the 30s, making the river unnavigable past the dam.

Comment: 1) If the paddle boat is small enough to put on a trailor, it could be driven by road around the dam.  2) if there are two different boats in the different episodes one might have always been upriver of the dam.  3) If the paddle box is too big to travel by road around the damn dam Marty might have done something epic like in Fitzcarraldo (1982) without it ever being shown onscreen.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitzcarraldo. 4)   Possibly Ozark happens in an alternate universe with some kind of lock for large vessels at the dam.